# jQuery Show/Hide trouble

Tags: jquery, html

I'm building this prev/next option to show another div but I'm walking into some weird problems.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cur = 0;
    var tbpages = ["#tb1", "#tb2", "#tb3", "#tb4"];
    //tb.volgende
    $("#next").click(function(){
        $(tbpages[cur]).hide();
        cur = cur + 1;
        $(tbpages[cur]).show();
    });
    //tb.vorige
    $("#back").click(function(){
        $(tbpages[cur]).hide();
        cur = cur - 1;
        $(tbpages[cur]).show();
    });
});
```

Now what happens: You start with `#tb1` open, click next (`#tb1` hides and `#tb2` opens), click next again, and nothing happens.

The divs `#tb1-4` all are identical (except from their content).

HTML:

```
<div id="tb1" class="praatwolk">
    <h2>Ik ben Theo</h2>
    <p>text</p>
    <center><button id="next">Volgende</button></center>
</div>
<div id="tb2" class="praatwolk" style="display: none;">
    <h2>Aanleiding/relevantie</h2>
    <p>text</p>
    <center><button id="back">Vorige</button><button id="next">Volgende</button></center>
</div>
<div id="tb3" class="praatwolk" style="display: none;">
    <h2>Wat is het theoretisch kader</h2>
    <p>text</p>
    <center><button id="back">Vorige</button><button id="next">Volgende</button></center>
</div>
<div id="tb4" class="praatwolk" style="display: none;">
    <h2>Bediening van de MOOC</h2>
    <p>text</p>
    <center><button id="back">Vorige</button><button id="next">Volgende</button></center>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we see some markup? I seriously doubt that you need an array of ID's to do this

Comment: I dont need an array of ID's yet, it's something i need later on. I tried doing it without first but got same results. What do you mean by markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you're using multiple `id`s with the same name `next`and `back`. This is not valid HTML and the browser is most likely to select the first element he finds. So when you click the second `next`-button the eventHandler is never triggered. Use the `class`-attribute instead if you want to address similar elements:

```
<button class="next">Volgende</button>
<button class="prev">Vorige</button>
```

The new selector:

```
$(".next").click(function(){});
$(".back").click(function(){});
```

Comment: Yess, this worked, never really knew this difference between class and id. Thanks alot!!

Answer (score 0):

Just test you `cur`number, if it is lower than `tbpages.length` then show you element.

```
if ( cur < tbpages.length ) {
   $(tbpages[cur]).show();
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qkccgruz/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have more than one element with the same id.

```
<center><button id="back">Vorige</button><button id="next">Volgende</button></center>
```

is defined three times at least. Try replace id="back" and id="next" with class="back" and class="next"

Answer (score 0):

This can be because the page is rendering more than one button with same id. I made some modification to your code and now it is working fine.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cur = 0;
    if(cur==0)
    $("#back").hide();
    else
    $("#back").show();

    var tbpages = ["#tb1", "#tb2", "#tb3", "#tb4"];
    //tb.volgende
    $("#next").click(function(){
$(tbpages[cur]).hide();
cur = cur + 1;    
if(cur==0)
    $("#back").hide();
    else
    $("#back").show();


        $(tbpages[cur]).show();
    });
    //tb.vorige
    $("#back").click(function(){
$(tbpages[cur]).hide();
 cur = cur - 1;
    if(cur==0)
    $("#back").hide();
    else
    $("#back").show();


        $(tbpages[cur]).show();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tb1" class="praatwolk">
        <h2>Ik ben Theo</h2>
        <p>text</p>

</div>
<div id="tb2" class="praatwolk" style="display: none;">
    <h2>Aanleiding/relevantie</h2>
    <p>text</p>

</div>
<div id="tb3" class="praatwolk" style="display: none;">
    <h2>Wat is het theoretisch kader</h2>
    <p>text</p>

</div>
<div id="tb4" class="praatwolk" style="display: none;">
    <h2>Bediening van de MOOC</h2>
    <p>text</p>
</div>
<center><button id="back">Vorige</button><button id="next">Volgende</button></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>


 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var cur = 0;
        var tbpages = ["#tb1", "#tb2", "#tb3", "#tb4"];
        //tb.volgende
        $("#next").click(function () {
            $(tbpages[cur]).hide();
            cur = cur + 1;
            $(tbpages[cur]).show();
        });
        //tb.vorige
        $("#back").click(function () {
            $(tbpages[cur]).hide();
            cur = cur - 1;
            $(tbpages[cur]).show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

```
<div id="tb1">1</div>
<div id="tb2" style="display:none">2</div>
<div id="tb3" style="display:none">3</div>
<div id="tb4" style="display:none">4</div>
<input type="button" id="next" value="Next" />
<input type="button" id="back" value="Back" />
```